# AngularJS Service: can't access child property

Tags: angularjs

I have created a service to get the details of a user once he logs in so I can feed this to all my angular controllers:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.service('authUser', ['$http', function ($http) {
var _currentUser = {};
$http.get("/Home/GetUser", {
    cache: false
}).success(function (data) {
    _currentUser.userid = data.userId;
    _currentUser.role = data.userRole;
    _currentUser.departmentid = data.departmentId;
    _currentUser.department = data.userDepartment;
});
this.currentUser = _currentUser;
}]);

app.controller('eventController', ['$scope', 'authUser', '$http', 'uiCalendarConfig', '$uibModal', function ($scope, authUser, $http, uiCalendarConfig, $uibModal) {
$scope.currentUser = authUser.currentUser;
```

When I try to display the output, it looks alright:

```
<div>
    <label>{{currentUser}}</label>
    <label>Id: {{currentUser.userid}}, Role: {{currentUser.role}}, Department Id: {{currentUser.departmentid}}, Department Name: {{currentUser.department}}</label>
</div>
```

This outputs:

```
{"userid":"29aa607a-d36b-46bb-a3a7-16bead5f4706","role":"Super 
Admin","departmentid":1,"department":"MIS"} Id: 29aa607a-d36b-46bb-a3a7-16bead5f4706, Role: Super Admin, Department Id: 1, Department Name: MIS
```

But when I try to use the properties of currentUser in my code, nothing is being passed. Example:

```
$http.get("/Home/GetVenues", {
    cache: false,
    params: {
        currentdepartment: $scope.currentUser.departmentid
    }
}).success(function (data) {
    // ...
})
```

I tried

```
$scope.currentdept = $scope.currentUser.departmentid;
```

Or

```
$scope.currentdept = authUser.currentUser.departmentid;
```

But both of these returns nothing ;m;

I'm apologize if I'm missing something really simple here, but I'm a potato please have mercy ;m;

If it is related at all here is my GetUser method from my HomeController:

```
public JsonResult GetUser()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var user = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(ApplicationDbContext.Create()));
            string id = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Id;
            IList<string> roleNames = userManager.GetRoles(id);
            ReservationsDatabaseModel dept = new ReservationsDatabaseModel();
            Department department = dept.Departments.Find(user.DepartmentID);

            userDepartmentRole user_department_role = new userDepartmentRole();
            user_department_role.userId = user.Id;
            user_department_role.departmentId = user.DepartmentID;
            user_department_role.userDepartment = department.Name;
            user_department_role.userRole = roleNames.FirstOrDefault();

            return new JsonResult { Data = user_department_role, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
        else
        {

            userDepartmentRole user_department_role = new userDepartmentRole();
            user_department_role.userId = "0";
            user_department_role.departmentId = 0;
            user_department_role.userDepartment = "0";
            user_department_role.userRole = "Guest";
            return new JsonResult { Data = user_department_role, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set `this.currentUser = _currentUser;` inside the success function

Comment: I tried that but now the output of 
    $scope.currentUser = authUser.currentUser; became empty: Id: , Role: , Department Id: , Department Name: ;m;

Comment: Can you give plunker link?

Comment: Sorry, I want to try, but I'm not sure how to because the user details are passed at user login and needs access from my localdb.

Comment: where did you put $http.get("/Home/GetVenues") call. Is it inside service or controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fetch of `/Home/GetVenues` needs to wait for the `authUser` data to arrive from the server.

Change the service to save a promise:

```
app.service('authUser', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var _ = this;
    this.currentUser = {};

    this.currentUserPromise = $http.get("/Home/GetUser", {
        cache: false
    }).then(function (response) {
        var data = response.data;
        _.currentUser.userid = data.userId;
        _.currentUser.role = data.userRole;
        _.currentUser.departmentid = data.departmentId;
        _.currentUser.department = data.userDepartment;
        return data;
    });
}]);
```

Then use that promise in the controller:

```
authUser.currentUserPromise.then(function(userData) {

    $http.get("/Home/GetVenues", {
        cache: false,
        params: {
            currentdepartment: userData.departmentid
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        var data = response.data;
        // ...
    })

});
```

This way the controller waits for the `authData` to arrive from the server before fetching from `/Home/GetVenues`.

Comment: sorry for late reply, we had a power outage so I just went to sleep ;m; Thank you for explaining what the problem was :D I followed this and it's working now, thanks a lot ^~^

Answer (score 0):

Your call should work only after `GetUser` API is returned, you can test by putting `GetVenues` call on a button click rather than running on init.